# Efficient way to parse a string with different index ranges

Tags: python, list, indexing

Suppose I have a string `M001P000J0Z987` with embedded codes that I want to cut up based on specific indexes. For example,
the first 4 (`[0:4]`) are a specific code, the next 4 (`[4:8]`) are another code, and the last 6 are (`[8:14]`).

This is fairly straightforward by doing:

```
codes = "M001P000J0Z987"

codes[0:4]
codes[4:8]
codes[8:14]
```

However, imagine I have dozens of these index combinations and need to parse thousands of different codes. Is there a more
efficient way to do this instead of writing a long function that does this line-by-line as shown above? The indexes don't change, it's just the codes that change. I need a way to pass in the index ranges (`[0:4]`), possibly as a list so I can use list compressions, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: have you considered regular expressions, like `re.match(r'(.{4})(.{4})(.{6})', codes)`

Comment: @gog I had not, but that seems like a good idea.

Comment: @gog is there a way to do this, but skip between index combinations? So instead of `0:4`and `4:8` it would be `2:4`and `6:8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an iterator on the string that you apply to the list of code sizes:

```
codes = "M001P000J0Z987"

sizes = [4,4,6]

iCodes = iter(codes)
values = [ "".join(map(next,[iCodes]*s)) for s in sizes ]

print(values)
['M001', 'P000', 'J0Z987']
```

if you don't mind using libraries, you can use accumulate to zip start and stop values for subscripts from the list of sizes:

```
codes = "M001P000J0Z987"
sizes = [4,4,6]

from itertools import accumulate
values = [codes[i:i+s] for i,s in zip(accumulate([0]+sizes),sizes)]

print(values)
['M001', 'P000', 'J0Z987']
```

If you're going to apply the same size pattern to multiple lines, you could set up a list of slices and use them in the extraction instead of using accumulate:

```
sizes  = [4,4,6]
starts = [0]
starts.extend(starts[-1]+s for s in sizes)
slices = [slice(i,i+s) for i,s in zip(starts,sizes)]


codelist  = ["M001P000J0Z987","Z001W012K0Z187","M012P999J0Q987"]
for codes in codelist:
    values = [codes[s] for s in slices]
    print(values)

['M001', 'P000', 'J0Z987']
['Z001', 'W012', 'K0Z187']
['M012', 'P999', 'J0Q987']
```

*note: `starts = [0] ; starts.extend(starts[-1]+s for s in sizes)`*

*is the same as: `starts = [0,*accumulate(sizes)]` but without itertools*

The same technique can be improved to produce dictionaries instead of merely breaking down the string into a list:

```
from itertools import accumulate

names  = ("A","B","C")
sizes  = ( 4,  4,  6 )
starts = [0,*accumulate(sizes)])]
slices = [(n,slice(i,i+s)) for n,i,s in zip(names,starts,sizes)]


codelist  = ["M001P000J0Z987","Z001W012K0Z187","M012P999J0Q987"]
for codes in codelist:
    values = { name:codes[s] for name,s in slices }
    print(values)

{'A': 'M001', 'B': 'P000', 'C': 'J0Z987'}
{'A': 'Z001', 'B': 'W012', 'C': 'K0Z187'}
{'A': 'M012', 'B': 'P999', 'C': 'J0Q987'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with 2 different methods, plus the regex which someone else suggested and timed them.

```py
# native.py
def parse(codes):
    return codes[:4], codes[4:8], codes[8:]
```

```py
# slices.py
ONE = slice(0, 4)
TWO = slice(4, 8)
THREE = slice(8, None)
def parse(codes):
    return codes[ONE], codes[TWO], codes[THREE]
```

```py
# regex.py
import re
PATTERN = re.compile(r"^(.{4})(.{4})(.{6})$")
def parse(codes):
    global PATTERN
    matched = PATTERN.match(codes)
    return matched.groups()
```

Here is my timing runs:

```bash
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'from native import parse' -- 'parse("M001P000J0Z987")'
2000000 loops, best of 5: 174 nsec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -s 'from slice import parse' -- 'parse("M001P000J0Z987")'
2000000 loops, best of 5: 146 nsec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -s 'from regex import parse' -- 'parse("M001P000J0Z987")'
1000000 loops, best of 5: 275 nsec per loop
```

#### Conclusion

- Using the slices `[:4]` ... is very fast
- Using a named slice (e.g. ONE) is faster, but not by much
- Using regular expression is slower, as I suspected.

There could be different methods which are faster still. For me, I vote for  using named slices because they are more descriptive.